# Double printing in an array data structure

Tags: java, arrays

I am having a hard time with my results. It was supposedly to print the highest and lowest grade of the person but it turns out it prints the same who had the highest score.

Output:

**Highest : Doyoung, 100**

**Lowest : Doyoung, 100**

and also it changes the showAllStudent Data and the grade.

Output:

**1. Doyoung - 100 - FAILED**

**2. Ramburat - 100 - PASSED**

Source code for Highest and Lowest

```
public static void highestLowest ()
{
    int max_index = 0;
    int min_index = 0;
    
    // Loop from index 0 to count of arrays
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        // Check for the index of max grade
        if(grade[i] > grade[max_index])
            grade[max_index] = grade[i];
        // Check for the index of min grade
        if(grade[i] < grade[min_index])
            grade[min_index] = grade[i];
    }
    
    System.out.println("Highest : " + name[max_index] + ", " + grade[max_index]);
    System.out.println("Lowest : " + name[min_index] + ", " + grade[min_index]);
    
    
}
```

Source code for ShowAllStudent Data

```
 public static void showAllStudents()
{
    // if count is 0 then no students in the list
    if(count == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("There are no registered student in ISCP");
    }
    else
    {
        // Loop from index 0 to count of arrays
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+1+". " + name[i] + " - " + grade[i] + " - " + result[i]);
        
        }
    }
}
```

Source code for static void main

```
 public static void main (String [] args)
{
    

    enlistStudent("Doyoung", 50);
    enlistStudent("Ramburat", 100);

    
    
    highestLowest();

    showAllStudents();  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating `grade` instead of the `min` and `max` indices. This

```
// Check for the index of max grade
if(grade[i] > grade[max_index])
    grade[max_index] = grade[i];
// Check for the index of min grade
if(grade[i] < grade[min_index])
    grade[min_index] = grade[i];
```

Should be

```
// Check for the index of max grade
if(grade[i] > grade[max_index])
    max_index = i;
// Check for the index of min grade
if(grade[i] < grade[min_index])
    min_index = i;
```